# Some Symbols Won't Appear in pdf

Tags: math-mode

I am a new user and I need some help! I think I've figured out the basics of creating a document, but certain symbols are not transferring into the pdf: the box, the diamond and the "force" turnstile. I don't know what the error messages mean or how to address them. I've attached screen shots of this and I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm missing because I'm just new to LaTeX. If anyone could help I'd be very grateful. [image: First Error Message][image: Error shot with messages]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: yes! exactly the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by the amssymb package for a (graphical) square. amssymb overwrites \square with no backup of amssymb’s original \square macro.
See http://www.combinatorics.net/weblib/a.8/a8.html. The table is divided into two parts. The top part contains the symbols provided by LaTex ; the last three commands requires the latexsym package.The bottom table lists symbols from the AMS ; they all require the amssymb package.